# How to convert asp.net web application to completely html5?

Tags: asp.net, image, html, iis

Iam doing a project in html5 only. i have connected webservices, get data from services using js. but unfortunately i got error in uploading images in base64 format on iis. so i convert my app to asp.net web application. ok for now. Is there any tools or softwares existing for converting my asp.net web application to html5 application????
please help me.

Comment: html5 is not synonymous with ASP.net or any other server side technology. Strongly advise you to read up further on those concepts first.

Comment: You could simply copy the html5 logo (http://www.w3.org/html/logo/) into your source folder. More seriously, you will have to be way more specific to get any useful reply. (ASP = server-side, HTML5 = client-side, though html5 is really a label for a mix-bag of technologies).

Answer (score 1):

Strictly speaking the only thing that makes a project html5 only is the fact that you use the html5 doctype declaration

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Title of the document</title>
</head>

<body>
The content of the document......
</body>

</html>
```

More info in the W3 [HTML5 reference](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html) and the [Base64 utility methods](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html#atob)